How to redefine the align environment in terms of itself?
I'm trying to redefine the amsmath equation environments to do some regex parsing of their contents. Something is going wrong with the environments that allow alignment tabs. Here's a MWE of the problem:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewCommandCopy\origequation\equation
\NewCommandCopy\endorigequation\endequation
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}{\origequation #1 \endorigequation}

\NewCommandCopy\origalign\align
\NewCommandCopy\endorigalign\endalign
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align}{b}{\origalign #1 \endorigalign}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} % Works fine
    x+y
\end{equation}

\begin{align} % Error: Misplaced alignment tab character &, ...
    x+y
\end{align}

\end{document}

Here, as an example, I'm attempting to trivially redefine both the equation and align environments without any modification. This works fine for equation, but with align I get errors about misplaced alignment characters. What would be the correct way to redefine align in terms of itself?

The start of the align environment looks for a * and forks accordingly. Also, I think you're probably trying to parse the & before you've started the align. You get the same kind of issue with tabular environments.

See page 14 of usrguide.pdf. (Not quite the same, but related.)

You are using \RenewDocumentEnvironment wrong: it expects four arguments, and with your current code you're just grabbing the \par token generated by the empty line as end-code. You should put the original end-code in the "new" end-code: \RenewDocumentEnvironment{align}{b}{\origalign#1}{\endorigalign}.

You're missing an argument to \RenewDocumentEnvironment, but it's not so important. The most relevant error is that \align and \endalign aren't really what you might expect.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{origequation}{equation}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}{\origequation#1\endorigequation}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{origalign}{align}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align}{b}
  {\begin{origalign}#1\end{origalign}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}

Text above text above text above text above text above
\begin{equation} % Works fine
    x+y
\end{equation}
text in between text in between text in between text in between
\begin{align} % Error: Misplaced alignment tab character &, ...
    x+y
\end{align}

\end{document}

However, you should not do this, because suddenly alignat and the other environments will probably cease to work.
If you really want to go along this road, then you need to redefine the end parts of all the alignment environments you use that are based on align.
Here's an example.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{origequation}{equation}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{equation}{b}{\origequation #1 \endorigequation}

\NewEnvironmentCopy{origalign}{align}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{align}{b}
  {\begin{origalign}#1\end{origalign}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}
%%%
\def\endalignat{\endorigalign}
% (...)

\begin{document}

Text above text above text above text above text above
\begin{equation} % Works fine
    x+y
\end{equation}
text in between text in between text in between text in between
\begin{align} % Error: Misplaced alignment tab character &, ...
    x+y
\end{align}
text in between text in between text in between text in between
\begin{alignat}{2} % Error: Misplaced alignment tab character &, ...
    x+y
\end{alignat}

\end{document}

Do yourself a favor and do
\NewDocumentEnvironment{ralign}{b}{%
  \begin{align}\dostuff{#1}\end{align}%
}{}

Of course, you know what you want to do with the environment's body.

Thanks, \NewEnvironmentCopy did the trick! But indeed, doing this to the align environment does break flalign and alignat. Is there any way to avoid that?

@srossd I told you that the other display alignment environments would break. Use a different name for the cases where you want to process the material before typesetting it.

@srossd I added some more text. Use the method I suggest at the end.

This is fantastic, thanks. I realize it would be much better practice to use a different name, but the goal here is to be able to inject \dostuff into an existing document with just a \usepackage line, so I appreciate the help in following the more dangerous road.

I don't quite agree. I mean, of course I agree with defining a different  environment instead of changing align, but I still believe that \endorigalign should go in the end code of the environment instead of leaving the latter empty. Your present code generates a spurious space after \end{ralign}. BTW, I think the end-code of {equation} is still missing right now \par is being grabbed). And your last snippet should probably be \NewDocumentEnvironment, not Command.

@campa I disagree about the “end part”. Of course, the objection about the space is sustained and fixed.

You should add a link to the documentation for the usage of \NewEnvironmentCopy.
